# PrimeNG Datatable does not allow add components to the rows

Tags: angular, datatable, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am using PrimeNG Datatable (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable) with lazy loading. Everything works great but I need to add a button in every row (with options to delete, edit each record).

I tried somehow to add the column in every row in the view, but couldn't figure it out.

Then I tried to add the HTML in the controller array that is used by the datatable:

```
private addActionsToRow(rows) {

    let rowsWithAction = [];
    for(let row of rows) {
        row['actions'] = '<div>Anything</div>'
        rowsWithAction.push(row);
    }

    return rowsWithAction;

}
```

However it does not evaluate the code and displays the plain HTML `<div>Anything</div>`.

It there a way to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with Templates, there is a section in Datatable doc (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable). I only needed to change `<ng-template>` to `<template>`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what i did to add a delete button to each row-

```
 <p-column [style]="{'width':'38px'}">        
      <ng-template let-h="rowData" pTemplate="body">
           <button class="ui-button-danger" type="button"  pButton (click)="deleteVendorRecord(h)" icon="fa-remove"></button>
      </ng-template>
 </p-column>
```

Then in the ts file created a function deleteVendorRecord that accepts a row

```
deleteVendorRecord(row):void{         
     this.vendorRecords.splice(this.vendorRecords.indexOf(row),1);            
}
```